# One dropdown list taking longer to load than another

Tags: javascript

I have a web page loading with javascript populating drop down lists.

The problem is that one dropdownlist is taking longer to load than the other, i.e. one is able to be clicked on straight away but the other takes a little longer to load and can't be clicked on until it has loaded.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: show your code please. It is only possible to help you by seeing the functions that populate that dropdown.

Comment: Are you populating that dropdown from a remote database? As @Jage said show us your code so we can see how you're populating. If it's from a remote database it may be caused by the delay time on the connection between the client and the database server.